# Binding a hyperlink in a Telerik grid to data on the client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a page that contains a RadGrid.  One of the columns contains a hyperlink in an edit template as so:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Asset Name" FilterControlAltText="FilterAssetName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hplEditAsset" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I'm loading the data through a webservice, so I'd like to bind data to the grid on the client side. I'm trying to access the hyperlink in a javascript function as follows:

```
function gridRowBound(sender, args) {
   var row = args.get_item()
   var link = $telerik.findElement(row , 'hplEditAsset');
   var d = args.get_dataItem();

   link.innerHtml = d.Url;
   link.outerHtml = d.UrlDescription; 
}
```

The data being bound to the grid is in the form of List, and MyDataRow has properties named Url and UrlDescription.

When I run the code, row is set to "tr#ctl00_MainContent_QuickScanGrid_ctl00__0.rgRow" according to Firebug. However, the script fails on the next line and link is never set.

How do I access that element so that I can bind the hyperlink to the data on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got excellent support help from Telerik on this. They had two alternative solutions:

1) A different type of call to findElement

```
function rowDataBound(sender, args) {
   var row = args.get_item();
   var d = args.get_dataItem();
   var link = $telerik.findElement(row.get_element(), 'hplEditAsset');

   $(link).text(d.ProductName);
}
```

OR

2)  Instead of a GridItemTemplate, use a GridHyperLinkColumn, which is designed to bind automatically exactly how I wanted it.

I chose the second way and it worked on the first try. I never tried the first method.

Overall, I have to say Telerik support for is excellent. Don't always get it right first time, but they stick with you, sometimes even after you determine the problem is not their control.